# How to update Sage Pay Token without payment process

Tags: opayo

What I like to know is how I can update a token when a card has expired without make any payments or amount. Is it possible?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Once a card token passes its expiry date, it is deleted from the Sage Pay system. You'll need to re-register the card.

Comment: Thanks Rik. What I did is make a new payment with 0.01p and then refund the transaction same time.

Comment: Once the transaction exists (ie: as a payment or whatever, distinct from a token), it is then possible to update the expiry date using the Reporting and Admin API....